# iOS Facebook Native Share Dialog : initial text

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm using Facebook Native Share Dialog in my iOS app. I give the initial text, but when dialog pop up, it add the post URL to my initial text. How can I solve this problem? Here the code.

```
BOOL displayedNativeDialog =
    [FBNativeDialogs
     presentShareDialogModallyFrom:self
     initialText:@"Say something about this..."
     image:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]
     url:[NSURL URLWithString:activityUrl]
     handler:^(FBNativeDialogResult result, NSError *error) {
         if (error) {
         } else {
             if (result == FBNativeDialogResultSucceeded) {
             } else {
             }
         }
     }];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're sharing a URL (link share) and the image is inside that link, then just set the image parameter to nil. Then the post URL will not be added to the initial text. If you provide an image, it's as if you're sharing a photo and adding the link (and text) as photo caption info.

So based on what you're trying to do, select the option that works for you, i.e. is it a link share or a photo share.